# jquery ajax submit form doesn't seem to use the Ajax route as XHR is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using jquery + AJAx to submit a form. I thought the form worked correctly as the data is stored in the DB as expected. 
But on future inspection it turns out the form doesn't submit with AJAX as with chrome devtools the XHR is empty. 
Normally, XHR will you me the file and Headers - Preview - Response, but now i don't see the file.

I noticed this problem as the form page reloads after submitting the form

Here's my logic, a simple function which is called after a succesfull form validation:

```
 function submitFormData() {
    var formData = new FormData($("#addform")[0]);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'add_data.php',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        processData: false,
        success: function (msg) {
            if (msg == 'ok') {
                $('#add_owner_name').val('');
                $('#add_owner_email').val('');
                $('#add_uri').val('');
                $('#statusMsg').html('<span style="color:green;">Thanks , we will review your suggestion.</p>');
                //$('#modal_addform').hide(); // Hide The Form

                //$("#modal_addform")[0].reset();
                $('#preview').attr('src', '//placehold.it/140?text=Impression');
            } else {
                $('#statusMsg').html('<span style="color:red;">Some problems occurred, please try again.</span>');
            }

        }
    });
}
```

And this the simple validation:

```
    (function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        } else {
             alert("submit data review");

             submitFormData();
             $('#addform').css("display","none");
        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated');
      }, false);
    });
  }, false);
})();
```

Comment: @alex can you please also post the HTML of your form !

Comment: well you do not cancel the form submission so Ajax call will happen along with the form submission and you will have a race condition. Page will submit and say goodbye to the Ajax call.

Answer (score 2):

You only call `preventDefault()` when the validity check fails. You need to call it when the `submitFormData()` function is executed as well, so move it outside the `if` statement. In fact you can invert the `if` statement for a better logic flow.

Also, remove `async: false`. It's incredibly bad practice and not needed here anyway. Similarly, `encType` should be removed when sending a FormData object.

```js
function submitFormData() {
  var formData = new FormData($("#addform")[0]);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'add_data.php',
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(msg) {
      if (msg == 'ok') {
        $('#add_owner_name').val('');
        $('#add_owner_email').val('');
        $('#add_uri').val('');
        $('#statusMsg').html('<span style="color:green;">Thanks , we will review your suggestion.</p>');
        $('#preview').attr('src', '//placehold.it/140?text=Impression');
      } else {
        $('#statusMsg').html('<span style="color:red;">Some problems occurred, please try again.</span>');
      }

    }
  });
}

(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        if (form.checkValidity() !== false) {
          submitFormData();
          $('#addform').css("display", "none");
        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated');
      }, false);
    });
  }, false);
})();
```

I would also suggest you return a strongly typed boolean value from your AJAX request indicating its success, instead of an `'ok'` string.

Finally note that the validation logic can be made more succinct when translated to jQuery:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.needs-validation').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    if (this.checkValidity() !== false) {
      submitFormData();
      $('#addform').hide();
    }

    $(this).addClass('was-validated');
  });
});
```

Comment: appreciate your explanation will readup and try your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that code might have been put together from various sources. It's better to understand the problems piece by piece.

You need to show us the HTML for the page as well. Almost certainly it will submit the form as normal (without ajax) because you aren't calling `event.preventDefault()` in the right place. This is what stops the form being submitted in the traditional manner.

To simplify the problem:

1. Assume your form has a submit button with an ID, `#submitBtn`
2. Look for a click on this button, then prevent the default action of the form submitting:

   ```
   $('#submitBtn').click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
   });
   ```
3. This takes care of the form being submitted "normally", i.e. without ajax.
4. After this you can do whatever you want, run client-side validation first (if you want), before making the ajax request.
5. Handle the ajax response appropriately. The form should always be validated server-side so an appropriate response should be given. Avoid using strings such as `"ok"`. Ideally return a JSON response and then work with it to determine success or failure in terms of the data submitted through the form, e.g.

   ```
   $.post('add_data.php').done(function(response) {
       // add_data.php should return JSON. 
       // You can access properties, e.g. response.status and/or console.log(response) to see what's been returned.
   }).fail(function() {
       // Handle ajax request failure
       // This is when making of the ajax request fails (e.g. network connection error) as opposed to a validation error of the form contents. It's important this is handled as well, as this situation is entirely possible.
   });
   ```

In PHP you could generate the JSON response like this:

```
echo json_encode(['success' => true]);
```

For example indicating a successful response. You can put any other properties in there as array keys/values. So in jquery you can access that with `response.success` inside the `.done()` callback.

Comment: i am playing around with your suggestion and using   `var formData =  $('#addform').serialize();`  it seems to work. But as my form also has a file input i need to use FormData `var formData = new FormData($("#addform")[0]);`
but this doesn't seem to work:
` $.post('add_data.php', formData).done(function(response) {`

Comment: a lot of google suggestions tell me to set  `contentType: false` and `processData: false` but I am not sure how to set this with $.post ?? $.ajax seems a bit clearer to me with setting the attributes, any tips?

Comment: Using `$.ajax` is fine since `$.post` and `$.get` are just sugar for making POST/GET ajax requests respectively. It would be good if you can post all the code you have on https://jsfiddle.net/ so I can see what's going on properly. Your original question concerns a form submitting in the traditional way as opposed to ajax. It sounds like the other issue may be a separate problem. I assume you've got it making the request via ajax now?